# What is the maven standard to make different kind of builds?

Tags: java, maven

I have a build cycle that is quite uncommon for Maven, and I don't know if I'm missing a feature or something.

I have a product that has 6 combinations of builds (for now), not mentioning the builds that vary depending on the environment set in the profiles (development, testing, release).

These combinations actually are the result of two variables, which are the application server that it'll run (Weblogic or JBoss), and the other is the database to be used (Oracle, PostgreSQL, MySQL). When I release that, I need to archive the 6 different .war combinations into a Nexus repository through a Jenkins build.

Each type of build changes 8-10 variables to make a proper build for the environment to be deployed.

I wanted something simple to change, just like the profile option, so I would change once just one variable and all the variables of the build would change automatically.

The only way to do this is making 6 different profiles for each environment resulting on 18 profiles like `development-weblogic-mysql`, `release-jboss-postgresql`, etc.?

Or there is a feature in Maven that I'm missing?

Comment: @chrylis The properties that change from one environment to another are not evaluated on runtime, they are evaluated before the context is up, so they are build-time variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can specify partial profiles for app container, db and environment

Then activate multiple profiles when building for example:

```
mvn package -P weblogic,mysql,development
```

also should you be doing environment specific builds (development/release/test)?

Comment: Whoa, I didn't know that. I'll try it now, if it works I'll come back and accept the answer...

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks a lot!